# How to update SQLite database without restarting activity?

Tags: java, android, json, sqlite

I have an app that at the start retrieves data from the cloud to update the database in the user's phone. I use an AsyncTask that shows a ProgressDialog while it downloads the data. The problem is that after the data is downloaded, the database updates only if I restart the activity after the dialog dissapears. This is kind of ugly and I would like to know if there is a better way to do that.

Here is the AsyncTask:

```
 class GetVersion extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

      @Override
      protected void onPreExecute() {
          super.onPreExecute();
          pDialog = new ProgressDialog(ListClubs.this);
          pDialog.setMessage(getString(R.string.updating));
          pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
          pDialog.setCancelable(false);
          pDialog.show();       
      }

    /**
     * Getting product details in background thread
     * */
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
       HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
       HttpPost updateCond = new HttpPost("http://website.com/update_db.php");
        //update database
         List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs2 = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
         nameValuePairs2.add(new BasicNameValuePair("version", Integer.toString(newVersion)));
         try {

                    updateCond.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs2));
                    HttpResponse response2 = httpclient.execute(updateCond);
                    String jsonResult2 = inputStreamToString(response2.getEntity().getContent()).toString();
                    //saving the JSONObject
                    JSONObject object2 = new JSONObject(jsonResult2);
                    JSONArray conditions = object2.getJSONArray("conditions");
                    //saving the version
                      for(int i = 0; i < conditions.length(); i++){
                        JSONObject c = conditions.getJSONObject(i);

                        int condId = c.getInt("id");
                        String condMon = c.getString("mon");

                        db.updateCond(condId, condMon);              

                  }
                    loginPrefsEditor.putBoolean("condBool", true); 
                    loginPrefsEditor.commit();      
                    Log.i("Update old version", Integer.toString(loginPreferences.getInt("oldV", -1)));

        return null;
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
        // dismiss the dialog once got all details

        pDialog.dismiss(); 
        restartActivity();

}    }
```

And this is the code for updateCond:

```
public int updateCond(int id, String newCond) {
       SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

       ContentValues values = new ContentValues();

       values.put(KEY_COND, newCond);

       // updating row
       return db.update(TABLE_COND, values, KEY_ID+"="+id,null );
   }
```

Comment: Did you try to do the database update in `onPostExecute` ? In `doInbackground`, you return a `JSONObject` instead of a String, and in `onPostExecute` you process this `JSONObject` and update the database

Comment: I changed my app and also the server files so I can do that and it worked!

Answer (score 0):

Try to do the database update in `onPostExecute`. In `doInbackground`, you return a `JSONObject` instead of a `String`, and in `onPostExecute` you process this `JSONObject` and update the database.